# Jetty deletes log file every day

Tags: java, logging, jetty

I have a fresh install of Jetty 9.4.4.v20170414. I enabled logging with:

```
java -jar start.jar --add-to-start=console-capture
```

and configured its settings in start.ini. `java -jar start.jar --list-config` gives this output:

```
...
jetty.console-capture.append = true
jetty.console-capture.dir = logs
jetty.console-capture.retainDays = 90
...
```

When jetty starts it creates log file in logs directory, it works just fine.

But the file is gone the next day and no new file for following day is created.

When I was using 9.3.x every day jetty just created another file to log into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to Jetty 9.4.5.v20170502

There was a nasty side effect of a different bug that is causing this, that was fixed with the 9.4.5 release.